# How make wp_nav() with my css?

Tags: php, html

I'm make small theme for company. We have html code made by fronted developer.
How will be code menu from html to wordpress by php.

```
  <nav class="top-nav">
      <a href="">О студии</a>
      <a href="pricing.html">Стоимость работ</a>
      <a href="">Галерея работ</a>
      <a href="">Важное о наращивании</a>
  </nav>
```

Comment: Did you read https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step is to register the name (or names) for your menus.  In your example, top-nav seems appropriate.

```
function vd_register_menu() {
  register_nav_menu('top-nav',__( 'Top Nav Menu' ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'vd_register_menu' );
```

This will allow you to build your menu items in the WP admin under Appearance > Menus.

To display your menu on the site, simply call the `wp_nav_menu()` function where you wish to print the code.

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'top-nav' ) ); ?>
```

Full documentation available via WP Codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus